# Nuxt build fail on Bit Bucket pipeline with AWS s3 bucket - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, deployment, heap-memory, cicd

I am deploying the nuxt 3 project from Bitbucket to AWS s3 bucket.

It throws the error `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory when running` npm run generate`. I have used node version` 19.3.0`

Please check the error screenshot [Here](https://i.imgur.com/Da6Fpb6.png)

I have tried to set `node --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/main` this line on the script but it returns another error `Module not found

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```js
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:19.3.0

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm set audit false
            - npm install
            - npm run generate
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          deployment: production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.1
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $AWS_BUCKET_NAME
                LOCAL_PATH: $AWS_LOCAL_PATH
                ACL: "public-read"
                CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=30672000"
                DELETE_FLAG: "true"
      - step:
          name: Clear CloudFlare Cache
          script:
            - curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/${CF_ZONE}/purge_cache" -H "X-Auth-Email:${CF_EMAIL}" -H "X-Auth-Key:${CF_AUTH_KEY}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
```